# Is this a DTO or a POCO or a combination of the two C#

Tags: c#, poco, dto

So below I have a class I created as an example of what I have been seeing and actually even started using this pattern myself as it tends to be quite useful for me. The problem is I have been calling it POCO but yet I believe a POCO really shouldn't have actual Data access included. I believe that is more for DTOs. So the question here is this DTO, POCO, a combination of the two or neither?

```
namespace MAINAPP.DAL
{

    public class SomeModel
    {
        public int SomeModelID { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }

        public static bool DeleteSomeModel(int SomeModelID)
        {
            bool returnstatus = true;
            int statusint = 0;
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeDBString"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    sc.Open();
                    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
                    query.Append("DELETE  FROM SomeModels WHERE SomeModelID = @SomeModelID");

                    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), sc))
                    {
                        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SomeModelID", SomeModelID));
                        statusint = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();


                        comm.Dispose();
                    }
                    sc.Close();
                    sc.Dispose();
                }

            }
            catch (SqlException se)
            {
                var exceptionresult = se.Message;

            }
            if (statusint > 0)
            {
                returnstatus = true;
            }
            else
            {

                returnstatus = false;
            }
            return returnstatus;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like some variation of Active Record pattern... http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a POCO nor is it a DTO.

A POCO is a Plain old CLR object, meaning that it has no dependencies and no base class derivations. The object you presented has a dependency on System.Data.

A DTO is traditionally used as a data contract only. DTO means that it really shouldn't have behavior because that behavior is not serializable. If someone were to consume the object from a WSDL definition and didn't have your class representation, they could not reproduce the DeleteSomeModel method.

If you want POCO classes, I'd suggest using the Repository pattern for your data access or use something like Code First in Entity Framework.

Here is an example using the repository pattern

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public int SomeModelID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class SomeModelRepository
{
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
       // delete logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: LOL So yeah I like I said I've been seeing this style quite a bit here and there. quite honestly it seems to work quite good I just never knew what exactly to call it. Do you see anything wrong with this style or what?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the repository pattern, it tends to work pretty well. The only thing I'd caution is making sure not to leak business logic into your repositories.